# Не читает и не записывает в БД SQLIte Java

Tags: java, sqlite, intellij-idea

возникла проблема. При подключении к БД не выводит никаких ошибок, так же и при записи и чтении из бд никаких ошибок нет, но при этом строки в таблицу не записываются и чтения строк тоже не происходит.

```
public class DB {
private static DB db;
private Connection co;
Statement st;




public static synchronized DB getDB() {
    if (db == null) {
        db = new DB();
        db.connect();
    }
    return db;
}

private DB(){

}

private void connect(){
    try{
        co = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:journal.db");

        System.out.println("connect...");

    }catch(SQLException ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

}

public ResultSet select(String query){

    ResultSet rs = null;
    try{

        st= co.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);

        st.close();
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }


     return rs;
}

public void insert(String query){
    try{
        st = co.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate(query);
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

}}




public abstract class Model {

private final DB db;

protected Model(){
    db = DB.getDB();
}

protected ResultSet select(String query){
    return db.select(query);
}

protected void insert(String query){
    db.insert(query);
}}



public class SampleModel extends Model {

public boolean isAuth(String login, String pass){
    insert("insert into users(login, password) values('admin', 'admin');");
    ResultSet rs = select("select * from users;");

    System.out.println("select * from users where login = '"+login+"' and password = '"+pass+"'");

    try {
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("login"));
            System.out.println(rs.getString("password"));
        }
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return true;
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разве можно statement закрывать пока читаем из ResultSet (в select)? И для записи попробуйте использовать не ExecuteQuery, а Execute.